# How to update object with another object in get_or_create?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have to tables wit similar fields and I want to copy objects from one table to another.
Problem that object could be absent in second table, so I have to use get_or_create() method:

```
#these are new products, they all are instances of NewProduct model, which is similar
#to Product model
new_products_list = [<NewProduct: EEEF0AP>, <NewProduct: XR3D-F>,<Product: XXID-F>]

#loop over them and check if they are already in database
for product in new_products_list:
    product, created = Products.objects.get_or_create(article=product.article)

    if created:
       #here is no problem because new object saved 
       pass
    else:
       # here I need to code that will update existing Product instance
       # with values from NewProduct instance fields
```

The case is that I don't want to list all fields for update manually, like this,, because I have about 30 of them:

```
update_old_product = Product(name=new_product.name,article= new_product.article)
```

Please advise more elegant way than above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the field names and update them in the the other `Product` instance:

```
for new_product in new_products_list:
    # use different variable names, otherwise you won't be able to access
    # the item from new_product_list here
    product, created = Products.objects.get_or_create(article=new_product.article)

    if not created:
       for field in new_product._meta.get_all_field_names():
           setattr(product, field, getattr(new_product, field))
       product.save()
```

Comment: that's great, but when I enter `product.save()` I'm getting such error `IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '2326209_FARNELL' for key 'product_product_article_4b591bee1bc47d02_uniq'")`

Comment: Perhaps one of the field in your new_product contains a value that is duplicate.

Comment: Error in article field, but it is unique, so it raised because ORM trying to create same object instead of updating one that exists. So how can I actually trigger update instead of create?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
def copy_fields(frm, to):
    id = to.id
    for field in frm.__class__._meta.fields:
        setattr(to, field.verbose_name, field._get_val_from_obj(frm))
    to.id = id
```

Answer (score -1):

This is similar to Ashwini Chaudhary, although I think it will take care of that error that you mentioned in the comments.

```
new_products_list= (
#   obj1, obj2, obj3 would be from [<NewProduct: EEEF0AP>, <NewProduct: XR3D-F>,<Product: XXID-F>] in your question
#   NewProduct would just be the model that you import
#   NewProduct._meta.fields would be all the fields
    (obj1, NewProduct, NewProduct._meta.fields,),
    (obj2, NewProduct, NewProduct._meta.fields,),
    (obj3, NewProduct, NewProduct._meta.fields,),
)

for instance, model, fields in new_products_list:
    new_fields = {}
    obj, created = model.objects.get_or_create(pk=instance.article) # this is pretty much just here to ensure that it is created for filter later
    for field in fields:
        if field != model._meta.pk: # do not want to update the pk
            new_fields[field.name] = request.POST[field.name]
    model.objects.filter(pk=question_id).update(**new_fields) # you won't have to worry about updating multiple models in the db because there can only be one instance with this pk
```

I know this was over a month ago, but I figured I would share my solution even if you have already figured it out